# Split rows into different sheets based on a column's value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 101 | 12:13:00 | employee |
| 102 | 12:15:00 | customer |
| 103 | 12:20:00 | employee |
| 102 | 12:16:00 | customer |
| 103 | 18:15:00 | employee |
| 101 | 18:18:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

how to separate rows to different sheets according to a column values automatically

finally get three sheets:

column a values 101

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 101 | 12:13:00 | employee |
| 101 | 18:18:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

column a values 102

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 102 | 12:15:00 | customer |
| 102 | 12:16:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

column a values 103

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 103 | 12:20:00 | employee |
| 103 | 18:15:00 | employee |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: many ways to do!! 1. apply a filter(in data tab) on column `a` and then copy the filetred ranges into another place 2. just sort the column `a` then.... 3. use look-up or index-match. 4. there are several excel add-ins to do this. 5. add a helper coulmn and populated based on look-up 6. use vba.....and so on. just google them!! BTW if you needs automatic creation of sheets then vba/add-ins are the ways to go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

*You need to create few Helper Columns in Sheet1.*

**Write following formula & fill down:**

D2 = `=IF($A2=101,1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")`

E2 = `=IF($A2=102,1+MAX($E$1:E1),"")`

F2 = `=IF($A2=103,1+MAX($F$1:F1),"")`

*Write following formula in **cell A2 of Sheet2** and copy this cell both across and down::*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!$D:$D,0)),"")
```

You get all records from Sheet 1 has ID 101.

**Note,**

- Use the above written formula For **ID 102 & 103** in **Sheet3 and
  Sheet4** with small modification.
- For **ID 102** replace `Sheet1!$D:$D` with `Sheet1!$E:$E` & for **ID 103**
  with `Sheet1!$F:$F`in the formula.

*Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*