# Excel - how do I filter multiple tables without header?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I want to filter if any of the H I J columns contain fields greater or equal to 10.0.

I don't want to use no Advanced filters because there are multiple tables across the way but I want to sort all of them.

*I don't think Advanced filter will work for me.

Please help - whatever I do - this seems like voodoo - I select H I J columns to be sorted then I select some other three columns for the criteria and write >=5.0 in the first one but nothing happens.

For difference the basic Filter will be able to sort me a single column above ten.

Comment: Insert a blank column before and after then use Autofilter.  Same for sorting . Inserts blank cells between tables you don’t want to merge for sorting or delete blank rows if you want to merge and sort.

Comment: @Nemo since you are not interested in `Advance Filter` then formula is the option left. My suggestion is create one `Helper Column` and apply this array formula,, `{=IF(OR(A150:A150>=10,B150:B150>=10),"show","hide")}`  fill it down,, finally apply `Auto Filter`.

Comment: ,,Continue,, Or just refer this https://superuser.com/questions/1347389 **recently I've posted solution this will also help you**.